# How do I test an excel spreadsheet with WIndows Application driver

Tags: c#, excel, windows, selenium, automation

I have run the Windows Application driver "calculator test" sample app.
Now, I would like to replace the Windows standard Calculator with an excel spreadsheet.

I want to plug values into the spreadsheet and retrieve the results .

I've looked through the source code on Github, but cannot recognize the calls to the Calculator App, nor do I know what the relevant calls to the Excel exe would be.

I need to find out how to launch Excel,  to plug values into excel, and then retrieve values from preset cells in an Excel spreadsheet.

Thanks

Comment: You need to find out how to launch Excel?

Comment: I'm going to repeat what I think you are trying to do and you can correct me.  You want to write a desktop application that launches Excel, and allows the application to write stuff into certain cells (numbers and formulas, I'm guessing), then let the Excel calculation engine do it's stuff, and, when Excel is finished calculating, you want to pull the result out of other Excel cells.  Is that correct?  Have you looked at other possible solutions to your problem?  Excel has a lot of extension points, but I don't have a clue how you might do this.

Comment: You can't find the calls to Calculator? Here they are: https://github.com/Microsoft/WinAppDriver/blob/master/Samples/C%23/CalculatorTest/ScenarioStandard.cs It's not a "call": it's finding a UI element (e.g. Button) and interacting with it (e.g. clicking on it)

Comment: @Flydog57 might be correct. This could be an XY problem. Do you want to learn test automation or do you want to automate Excel? That's a big difference.

Comment: @Weller @ Flydog5  I want to do to Excel what the CalculatorTest does with Windows calculator.  I have used automation to test Apps, and Websites, I thought i could do excel, but cannot find the commands to do so

Answer (score 0):

Ah well, I decided to test the excel spreadsheet by hand.  It was getting complicated for something I can do quickly by hand. Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score -2):

Example:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application ObjExcel;
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook ObjWorkBook;
        private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ObjWorkSheet;

string fileName = System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\" + textBox1.Text + ".xlsx";
            MessageBox.Show(fileName);
            try
            {
                ObjExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

                ObjWorkBook = ObjExcel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);

                ObjWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)ObjWorkBook.Sheets[1];


                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[i]; 
                    for (int j = 0; j < row.Cells.Count; j++) 
                    {ObjExcel.Cells[1, 1]="id";
                ObjExcel.Cells[1, 1]="column";
                ObjExcel.Cells[1, 2]="column";
                ObjExcel.Cells[1, 3]="column";
                        ObjExcel.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = row.Cells[j].Value;
                    }
                }
                ObjWorkBook.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error"); }

            ObjWorkBook.Close(null, System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\" + textBox1.Text + ".xlsx", null);

                    ObjExcel.Quit();
                    ObjWorkBook = null;
                    ObjWorkSheet = null;
                    ObjExcel = null;
                    GC.Collect();

            this.Text = this.Text + " - " + textBox1.Text + ".xlsx";
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with GUI automation

Comment: The question was about using excel tools for computing. I gave an example of creating and populating an excel table with c #

Comment: @ThomasWeller: how are you sure this isn't what the OP is asking about?

Comment: @Flydog57: the title includes "with Windows Application driver" and this answer has nothing to do with that

Comment: @DeviceThanks for the effort, VBA or c# in VS is not the thing here,  the idea is to automate the testing of the excel spreadsheet via the GUI, that is like a human interacting with the spreadsheet.

Comment: @Ola Sorry. Looks like I misunderstood your question